# IIS 8.5 PHP 5.6.2 x64 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of... if imagick is enabled

Tags: windows, memory, php, iis

I changed from PHP 5.6.2 x86 (nts) to x64 (nts) on IIS 8.5 and I got almost every extension to work except imagick.

I tried to update imagick binaries to the latest x64 dll version *(6.8.9-8-Q16-x64-dll)* but did not help. Oh and of course I tried x86 binaries too.

I re downloaded the imagick php extension from php.net *(php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-nts-vc11-x64)*
But it didn't helped.

Increasing the memory limit didn't made any difference.

The moment I try to run any php script *(php info included)* than I get the http 500 error. In the error log every time I reload php_info() it tries to allocate a different size of memory and it runs into this error even when the memory_limit is higher than the size it tries to allocate.

What could be the problem?

here is some php.ini setting

```
memory_limit = 256M
cgi.force_redirect = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0
max_execution_time = 300
date.timezone = Europe/Budapest

[PHP_WINCACHE]
extension=php_wincache.dll

[PHP_IMAGICK]
extension=php_imagick.dll

[SourceGuardian]
extension=ixed.5.6.win
```

and here is my error log:

```
[17-Oct-2014 05:32:30 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
[17-Oct-2014 05:32:30 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2668343408 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Oct-2014 05:35:01 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
[17-Oct-2014 05:35:01 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2102673520 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Oct-2014 05:40:22 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
[17-Oct-2014 05:40:22 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3299324016 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```